# Capitalize Words in PHP with custom delimitor

Tags: php, string, methods, capitalization

I need a method to capitalize every first letter of a word. 
This is what i got so far and it is working for almost every string...but it fails on this one "WELLNESS & RENOMME".

```
    // method in stringModify Class
    function capitalizeWords($words, $charList) {

    $capitalizeNext = true;

    for ($i = 0, $max = strlen($words); $i < $max; $i++) {
        if (strpos($charList, $words[$i]) !== false) {
            $`capitalizeNext` = true;
        } else if ($capitalizeNext) {
            $capitalizeNext = false;
            $words[$i] = strtoupper($words[$i]);
        }
    }

    return $words;
    }
    // Calling method
   $stringModify->capitalizeWords("WELLNESS & RENOMME", " -&");
```

I hope someone can help me out...i tried for 1,5 hours now and don't have a clue. Thanks in advance for any tips or hints.

#### edit

ucwords() uses " " as delimitor and i want to use "-" for example too.

#### edit

thanks to you all for you solutions. i will go to bed now, its 7 in the morning here. :D i will see which solution i like best when i wake up and then tell you which one i choosed.

#### edit

it seems like all the functions are returning "wellness &Amp; Renomme" or "wellness & Renomme". is it possible that something in my php.ini is messed up?

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused at what exactly you're trying to do. PHP already has a [`ucwords()`](http://www.php.net/ucwords) function that can do this and I don't see any difference in what you're doing... If you're capitalizing the first letter of each word, do delimiters make any difference? Does it matter at all that there's a '&' between the two words?

**Edit:** I think I understand now. I assume the only problem you're having is that you can't tell it's uppercasing the text because it's already all uppercased, all you need to do is lowercase it first. I also changed it to completely get rid of the 'next character' thing, it was unnecessary. If you find a match, just change the next character to uppercase. Try this:

```
// method in stringModify Class
function capitalizeWords($words, $charList) {
    $words = strtolower($words); // lowercase everything that isn't capitalized
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($words); $i++) {
        if (strpos($charList, $words[$i]) !== false) $words[$i+1] = strtoupper($words[$i+1]);
    }
    return $words;
}
// Calling method
$stringModify->capitalizeWords("WELLNESS & RENOMME", " -&");
```

Comment: this returns "wellness &Amp; Renomme" for me.

Comment: That's odd, I realize now I forgot to capitalize the first letter, but `strtoupper` and `strtolower` would not convert the '&' to '&amp;'... I've thought up an alternative way, but Erik has pretty well covered it. I'll go ahead and type it up though.

Comment: Since it won't let me edit my comment: It does not convert it to '&amp;' for me, you must be doing something to the text before it reached the function. I put it into a test PHP page and it returned 'wellness & Renomme'.

Comment: // result:
Array ( [name] => wellness &Amp; Renomme [name2] => WELLNESS & RENOMME )

//Method Calling:
$hsql_results[name] = $strMod->capitalizeWords($dummy, ' -&');
$hsql_results[name2] = $dummy;

i dont get it, no function on the internet is working for this string on my computer. :-D

Answer (score 1):

```
function cb($word){ return ucwords(strtolower($word[0])); }
var_dump(preg_replace_callback('@[A-z]+@i','cb','TESTING-TESTING / TESTING & TEST / testing*&^123!&%&*TEST'));
```

Comment: `[A-z]` includes more characters than intended and is usually inapproprite/incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

For converting the first letter capital in all sentence use the below code.

Ex)

```
$string = strtolower($string);
echo preg_replace('/(^|[\.!?]"?\s+)([a-z])/e', '"$1" . ucfirst("$2")', $string); 
?>
```

Comment: The `e` modifier is no longer in use. A dot does not need to be escaped in a character class.